# Sou iniciante em SQL. Preciso construir um insert que faça uma validação de alguns campos da tabela de origem e preencha na tabela de destino

Tags: sql, oracle

Sei que a situação nao faz muito sentido, mas o importante pra min é entender como fazer o "copiar e colar" de uma tabela pra outra de acordo com uma condição.

As tabelas são as seguintes:

| Produtos_temp | Produtos |
| --- | --- |
| ID | ID |
| Nome | Nome |
| V_total | V_total |
| V_ISS | V_ISS |
| V_Aliquota | V_Aliquota |
| Data_Criacao | Data_Criacao |
|  | Data_Validacao |

Tudo da Tabela Produtos_temp será inserido na tabela Produtos. O que muda é só o campo Data_Validacao.

Essa é a validação: V_ISS = (V_total * V_Aliquota) / 100

Caso V_ISS seja igual a (V_total * V_Aliquota) / 100, Copiar a data do campo Data_Criacao da tabela de origem e repetir no campo Data_Validacao da tabela de destino.

Caso V_ISS esteja diferente de (V_total * V_Aliquota) / 100, deixar o campo Data_Validacao como NULL.

Tentei fazer essa validação usando CASE WHEN mas nao consegui. Só sei fazer o insert direto. Quem puder me ajudar, desde já muito obrigado !!

Comment: *"é entender como fazer o "copiar e colar" de uma tabela pra outra"* primeiro faça o select da tabela de onde quer copiar voltar os dados que deseja, depois coloque isse select junto com um insert: `insert into produtos (campos) select campos from Produtos_temp where sua condição`

Comment: Explique melhor o problema , é uma solução pontual ou vai funcionar assim em produção ? Em que momento é esta inserção ? Em tese uma TRIGGER poderia fazer a validação e a inserção mas o assunto ainda me parece "gasoso".

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso basta usar o merge.

```sql
merge into Produtos p using (Produtos_temp temp) on (temp.V_ISS = temp.V_total * temp.V_Aliquota /100)
when matched then update set p.Data_Validacao = null
when not matched then insert (temp.id, temp.Nome, temp.V_total, temp.V_ISS, temp.V_Aliquota, temp.Data_Criacao) values
(p.id, p.Nome, p.V_total, p.V_ISS, p.V_Aliquota, p.Data_Criacao)
```

Answer (score -3):

Faz select antes de inserir. No select você faz a validação dos registros a serem inseridos, e na sequência faz o insert